# PyQt5: QtMultimediea wmfengine.dll not loading - no audio, no video

Tags: python, qt, dll, pyqt, qtmultimedia

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that `QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin()` calls `QLibraryPrivate::load()`, which in turn calls `QLibraryPrivate::load_sys()`. I have looked into the underlying process and found this snippet of the [`QLibraryPrivate::load_sys()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/plugin/qlibrary_win.cpp.html) function:

```
    for (const QString &attempt : qAsConst(attempts)) {
#ifndef Q_OS_WINRT
        pHnd = LoadLibrary((wchar_t*)QDir::toNativeSeparators(attempt).utf16());
#else // Q_OS_WINRT
        QString path = QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::current().relativeFilePath(attempt));
        pHnd = LoadPackagedLibrary((LPCWSTR)path.utf16(), 0);
        if (pHnd)
            qualifiedFileName = attempt;
#endif // !Q_OS_WINRT
        // If we have a handle or the last error is something other than "unable
        // to find the module", then bail out
        if (pHnd || ::GetLastError() != ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND)
            break;
    }
#ifndef Q_OS_WINRT
    SetErrorMode(oldmode);
#endif
    if (!pHnd) {
        errorString = QLibrary::tr("Cannot load library %1: %2").arg(
                    QDir::toNativeSeparators(fileName), qt_error_string());
    }
```

Looking at the `if (!pHnd) {`, you can see that is where the error string is generated. Now what is causing pHnd to be NULL/False? Well above it is set to the return value of [`LoadPackagedLibrary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447159(v=vs.85).aspx), which must always be returning NULL, otherwise the error string would not be set and `qualifiedFileName` would be valid and the library would be loaded.

So if someone can tell me why `LoadPackagedLibrary()` is failing to load `wmfengine.dll` then I could possibly fix something on my system to ensure a successful load.

---

I am trying to play some audio using PyQt5. Here is a snippet:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtGui
import PyQt5
import sys, os

os.environ['QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS'] = "1"

pyqt = os.path.dirname(PyQt5.__file__)
QtWidgets.QApplication.addLibraryPath(os.path.join(pyqt, "mediaservice"))

app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
music = os.path.join(pyqt, "mysong.mp3")
sound = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(music))
player.setMedia(sound)
player.setVolume(100)
player.play()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, I get this error:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

Upon further inspection with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`, I get some more details:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Programming/QTApps/Browser/venv/Scripts/mediaservice/wmfengine.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/Programming/QTApps/Browser/venv/Scripts/mediaservice/wmfengine.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "windowsmediafoundation"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer",
            "org.qt-project.qt.audiodecode"
        ]
    },
    "className": "WMFServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 328960
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("windowsmediafoundation")
loaded library "C:/Programming/QTApps/Browser/venv/Scripts/mediaservice/wmfengine.dll"
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "C:/Programming/QTApps/Browser/venv/Scripts/mediaservice/wmfengine.dll" : "Cannot load library C:/Programming/QTApps/Browser/venv/Scripts/mediaservice/wmfengine.dll: The specified module could not be found."
```

This is odd, because the `wmfengine.dll` is indeed there, which the system recognizes and is able to pull metadata from. Also, other plugins in the same parent directory are loaded successfully, just not this one, so it is not an issue of being located properly. Additionally, it says it loads the library, but on the next line says it cannot?

I am not sure how relevant this is, but I used [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to look at `wmfengine.dll` and I found a lot of errors/missing dependencies:

[image: What I see in Dependency Walker]

Here is a full list of all the missing .dlls:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPINIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ATOMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-MIDLPROXYSTUB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COMM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L3-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HANDLE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-INTERLOCKED-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LARGEINTEGER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-OBSOLETE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMESPACE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NORMALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PERFCOUNTERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSSNAPSHOT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-ANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-KEY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRYUSERSPECIFIC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHLWAPI-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHLWAPI-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRINGANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSTEMTOPOLOGY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSTEMTOPOLOGY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TIMEZONE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-URL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-UTIL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSIONANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-XSTATE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-CONFIG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CLASSICPROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONTROLLER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-GDI-DPIINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-UAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-TIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-APPCONTAINER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPABILITY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-WINSVC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELLCOM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELLFOLDERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-STORAGE-EXPORTS-EXTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-STORAGE-EXPORTS-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EVR.DLL
MF.DLL
MFPLAT.DLL
MFREADWRITE.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-IDENTITY-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-STATE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-UNLOCK-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-BASE-UTIL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CALENDAR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-MINIDUMP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIRMWARE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALREGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MARSHAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-5.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-APP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-APPNOTIFY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TOOLHELP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSIONANSI-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERRORPRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-PROPERTYSETPRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-PROPERTYSETPRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REGISTRATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-COREUI-SECRUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-HEAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-LOCALE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-MATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-PROCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-TIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CRT-UTILITY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-ADVAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-ADVAPI32-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-KERNEL32-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-NORMALIZ-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-OLE32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHELL32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-USER32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-VERSION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DWMAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-TDH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTLOG-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-HTTP-TIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-JOYSTICK-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MISC-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-INTERFACECONTEXTS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NTUSER-RECTANGLE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-OLE32-IE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-OOBE-NOTIFICATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-SETTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RO-TYPERESOLUTION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-CLIPBOARD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SHELL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINEVENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACCESSHLPR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTOAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ISOLATEDCONTAINER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LOGON-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LOGON-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-ANSI-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSAPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDLPARSECOND-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SYSTEMFUNCTIONS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-COMHELPERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-STREAM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-STREAM-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-THREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-UNICODEANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-CHANGENOTIFY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-NAMESPACE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHDIRECTORY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHLWAPI-IE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHLWAPI-WINRT-STORAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
DEVICELOCKHELPERS.DLL
EMCLIENT.DLL
EXT-MS-MF-PAL-L2-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPCHROMEAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPDEFAULTS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-EMCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-INTERNAL-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-DCOMP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-HLINK-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-ORIENTATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-PHONEINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-SHELLCHROMEAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-SHELLCHROMEAPI-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-LSA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-MSI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NPUSERNAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NTMARTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-PSM-APP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-SAFER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPCOMPAT-AEPIC-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPCOMPAT-APPHELP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DAXCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DAXCORE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DEPLOYMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RESTRICTEDAPPCONTAINER-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-STATE-EXT-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-USERCONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-VIEWSCALEFACTOR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOYONECORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUDIOCORE-PAL-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-CONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-CLBCATQ-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-COML2-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-4.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-5.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-PSMREGISTER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-SUSPENDRESILIENCY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DESKTOPAPPX-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-DM-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DIRECT2D-DESKTOP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DOMAINJOIN-NETJOIN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DWMAPI-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DWMAPIDXGI-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EDPUTIL-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EDPUTIL-POLICY-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ELS-ELSCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EVENTING-RUNDOWN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FAMILYSAFETY-CHILDACCOUNT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FIREWALLAPI-WEBPROXY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FVEAPI-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-CLIPPING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-CREATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DEVCAPS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-GDIPLUS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRINT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-RENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-WCS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GPAPI-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GUI-DUI70-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-IMM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-DATETIME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-CURRENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNELBASE-PROCESSTHREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MININPUT-INPUTHOST-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MPR-MULTIPLEPROVIDERROUTER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MRMCORER-ENVIRONMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MRMCORER-RESMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-WCMAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-WLANSTORAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DC-ACCESS-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DIALOGBOX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DRAW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DRAW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DRAW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-GUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-KEYBOARD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MENU-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-5-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-5-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MIT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MOUSE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-3-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-RECTANGLE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-ROTATIONMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SERVER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOWCLASS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOWSTATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ODBC-ODBC32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-BINDCTX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-IE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-OLEAUTOMATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLEACC-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PRINTER-PRNTVPT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-EXTENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-LOAD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-USERENV-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-USERENV-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RAS-RASAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RAS-TAPI32-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RDR-DAVHLPR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RESOURCES-DEPLOYMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RO-TYPERESOLUTION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RPC-SSL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-DEVCAPS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-OBJECT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-RGN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-RGN-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-INPUT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-PRIVATE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-CURSOR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DC-ACCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DPI-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-IAM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-INTEGRATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYNCH-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSCOLORS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECUR32-TRANSLATENAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPAUTHZ-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPAUTHZ-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CHAMBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDUI-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDUI-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTUI-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFSWRT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFSWRT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-WINSCARD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-WINSCARD-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-USERMGR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-USERTOKEN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-WINSTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-WTSAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SETUPAPI-INF-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SETUPAPI-INF-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-DIRECTORY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-EMBEDDEDMODE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELL32-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL32-SHELLCOM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL32-SHELLFOLDERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SMBSHARE-BROWSERCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-STORAGE-SENSE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-STORAGE-SENSE-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SXS-OLEAUTOMATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-TSF-MSCTF-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-TSF-MSCTF-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-UI-VIEWMANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-USP10-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-UI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-XBOX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-DEVICE-ACCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-STORAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WLAN-ONEXUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WLAN-SCARD-L1-1-0.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

I am running PyQt5 v5.5 x64 on Python 3.4 inside of a virtualenv. OS is Windows 10 64bit.

Ideas? I can provide any more info you might think is relevant.

Comment: Set a different backend and try again. Could be also due to virtual machine. MSCore warnings can be ignored.

Comment: @user3606329 can you elaborate on what you mean by 'setting a different backend'? Also, I am not running in a virtual machine - only a virtual environment, which is a Python package for isolated interpreters/packages.